# What is the fsyacc equivalent for the following ocamlyacc code?

Tags: f#, fsyacc

I'm working on a toy compiler using F#, i.e., the combo of FsLex and FsYacc. To get familiar with them, I've read the Lexer/Parser chapter of Expert F# (v2) book (a good book btw). Right now, I've half way through the well-recommended ocamlyacc tutorial, and stuck at the last example Multi-Function Calculator [mfcalc](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamlyacc-tutorial/sec-multi-function-calculator.html). Particularly, the following statement

```
%token <float->float> FNCT
```

in the parser file keeps getting error "error: parse error" in my [F# version](https://gist.github.com/909140). Am I missing anything here, or is this a feature currently not supported by F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Adding parens doesn't help. I have tried various workarounds, but I couldn't find a clean way. You should do a bug report.

If you have only one function (like in the tutorial example), you should define a type in the prelude:

```
type floatFunction = float -> float
...
%token <floatFunction> FNCT
```

If you have many functions, you could also define a generic type:

```
type functionType<'a, 'b> = 'a -> 'b
...
%token < ('a, 'b) functionType > FNCT
```

Any angle bracket in the type leads to a parse error (even `functionType<float,float>`).

Comment: I tried the approach as you suggested. It resolved the issue. Thanks. BTW, I still consider the ocamlyacc syntax in this case, looks much cleaner and more natural.

Comment: Just sent a bug report to the F# team.

Comment: @Cygwin98 Did they fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put parens, like

```
%token <(float->float)> FNCT
```

I forget (am away from an F# machine to check).

Comment: Hi, Brian, I added parens and now the error changed to Parser.fsy(11,21): error: Unexpected character ')'